# How to get the FTP file names printed descending order using java?

Tags: java, sftp, r.java-file

I have to get the last three uploaded file names,sizes, and its uploaded times in Descending order from my FTP server.
But I can only able to print all the files with names,sizes,and upload time too.
But its Enough to get Last three uploaded file and its size,uploaded time.

My exact objective is to get the uploading details of my FTP server to ensure the files are uploading properly.

Can any one help me to achieve this ?

```
package com;
import java.io.File;
import edu.vt.middleware.crypt.io.TeePrintStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPConnectMode;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPTransferType;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.Protocol;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.SecureFileTransferClient;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import edu.vt.middleware.crypt.io.TeePrintStream;
public class getFilesFTP
{
public static File dir=new File("D:/log_FTPCHECK");
 public static String logname="output.txt";
 public static File logfile=new File(dir,logname);
 public static StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
 public static byte[] filesize;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception

{
    sb.append("*******************************************
************************************************
***************************************************************");
    sb.append("<p align=center><B><U>SCOPUS FILE UPLOAD CHECK AUTO   
GENERATED LOG REPORT</U></B></p>");
sb.append("************************************************
*************************************************************
*********************************************");

String host="sftp-opsbank2.elsevier.com";
String username="tho-e";
String password="Tho5540b2E";
int count=0;
File Filename;;
Date FileDate;
String invalidfilename=".";
String filetype="";
 //DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/year");
 //String date1="";
String Lastmodifieddata="";
String Lastmodifieddata_time="";
Date todayDate;
     try{

         SimpleDateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
         SimpleDateFormat Format_time=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd   
HH:mm:ss");
     String timeStamp = 
dateformat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        // System.out.println("I am executed2");
           // System.out.println("Todays Date :"+timeStamp );
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            //sb.append("Todays Date :"+timeStamp );    
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
           // System.out.println("I am executed2");
            SecureFileTransferClient client=new 
SecureFileTransferClient();            
client.getAdvancedFTPSettings().setConnectMode(FTPConnectMode.PASV);

            client.setRemoteHost(host);
            client.setUserName(username);
            client.setPassword(password);
            client.setProtocol(Protocol.SFTP);
            client.setRemotePort(22);

            client.setContentType(FTPTransferType.BINARY);
         //      sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
             System.out.println("connecting to sftp...");
          //     sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("connecting to sftp...");
             sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            client.connect();
            System.out.println("SFTP Connection established 
successfully.");
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("SFTP Connection established successfully.");
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

            String path1="/sftp/content-providers/tho-e/data/incoming
/scopusbk";
            com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPFile[] directroy = 
client.directoryList(path1);
            System.out.println("Total Number of Files Found 
:"+directroy.length);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            //sb.append("Total Number of Files Found 
:"+directroy.length);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            int x=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < directroy.length; i++) 
            {
                //System.out.println("entered in for loop");
                Filename= new File(directroy[i].getName());
                FileDate=(Date) directroy[i].lastModified();
                //Filetype=getFileExtension(Filename);
            //  System.out.println("Name:"+Filename);

  Lastmodifieddata=dateformat.format(directroy[i].
  lastModified());            
 Lastmodifieddata_time=Format_time.format(directroy[i].lastModified());

                //filesize=directroy[i].getName().getBytes();
                long size = directroy[i].size();

                if(timeStamp.equalsIgnoreCase(Lastmodifieddata))


                {   
                    if ((directroy[i]).getName().endsWith("txt"))
                    {

                System.out.println("File Name : "+Filename + " ||  
Upload Time :  "+Lastmodifieddata_time+"  || Size  : "+size+" kb");
                 sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                sb.append("File Name : "+Filename + " ||  Upload Time :  
"+Lastmodifieddata_time+"  ||  Size  : "+size+" kb");
                 sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                //System.out.println();


                // String path1="/sftp/suppliers/thomdi/signals
/ContentCAR";
                // com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPFile[] directroy = 
client.directoryList(path1);
                count++;
                    //}
            }





                }

                else
                {
                    //System.out.println("No todays files");
                }
     }



            if(count>0)
            {
            System.out.println("Total Number of files :"+count);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("Total Number of file :"+count);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());          

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No Files uploaded today....!!!");
                  sb.append("No Files uploaded today....!!!");
            }


          //  PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new 
FileOutputStream("D:/output.txt"));
          //  System.setOut(out);
            if(!logfile.exists())
            {
            logfile.createNewFile();
            }



            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(logfile,sb.toString());

            FTPMailer.sendmailFTP();

            count=0;


     }
     catch(SecurityException se)
     {
         System.out.println("Security credentials mismatch 
issue...Unable to Login ");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         sb.append("Security credentials mismatch issue...Unable to 
Login ");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         se.printStackTrace();

     }
     catch(ConnectException ce)
     {
         System.out.println("Unable to Reach FTP Server..");
         System.out.println("Check the Internet Connectivity");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         sb.append("Unable to Reach FTP Server..");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         sb.append("Check the Internet Connectivity");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
     }

}
}
```

Comment: Have a look on my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335826/how-to-sort-sftp-files-order-by-last-updated-time-using-java#35338654) to your other [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335826/how-to-sort-sftp-files-order-by-last-updated-time-using-java).

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all relevant file information in a `List`. After your loop over all files of the directory you can then sort the `List` by the timestamp of the files; the first (or last, depending on your sort order) three entries are the ones you are looking for.