# How to sort SFTP Files order by last updated time using java?

Tags: java, sorting, ftp, sftp

[image: please click here to see the unwanted file name][image]I am having a set of text files in my FTP server.

I want to Read all the files are all uploaded by today.

and among that i have to print the last three uploaded file's properties.
(name,uploaded time,size).
Now i will be able to print name and properties of the filed present in FTP server but its not in a order and displays like a junk.
Now i want to print the name,size,path,upload time of the last three uploaded files.

Can any one help me to achieve this?

Here are my snippet:

```
package com;
import java.io.File;
import edu.vt.middleware.crypt.io.TeePrintStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
//import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPConnectMode;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPTransferType;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.Protocol;
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.SecureFileTransferClient;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import edu.vt.middleware.crypt.io.TeePrintStream;
public class getFilesFTP
{
public static File dir=new File("D:/log_FTPCHECK");
 public static String logname="output.txt";
 public static File logfile=new File(dir,logname);
 public static StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
 public static byte[] filesize;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
       sb.append("*************************************
************************************************
*********************************************************************");
    sb.append("<p align=center><B><U>SCOPUS FILE UPLOAD CHECK AUTO  
GENERATED LOG REPORT</U></B></p>");
    sb.append("***********************************************
****************************************************************
*******************************************");  
String host="example.com";
String username="john";
String password="doe";
int count=0;
File Filename;;
Date FileDate;
String invalidfilename=".";
String filetype="";
//DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/year");
//String date1="";
String Lastmodifieddata="";
String Lastmodifieddata_time="";
Date todayDate;

     try{

         SimpleDateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
         SimpleDateFormat Format_time=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd 
HH:mm:ss");
     String timeStamp = 
dateformat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        // System.out.println("I am executed2");
           // System.out.println("Todays Date :"+timeStamp );
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            //sb.append("Todays Date :"+timeStamp );    
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
           // System.out.println("I am executed2");
            SecureFileTransferClient client=new 
SecureFileTransferClient();            
client.getAdvancedFTPSettings().setConnectMode(FTPConnectMode.PASV);

            client.setRemoteHost(host);
            client.setUserName(username);
            client.setPassword(password);
            client.setProtocol(Protocol.SFTP);
            client.setRemotePort(22);

            client.setContentType(FTPTransferType.BINARY);
         //      sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
             System.out.println("connecting to sftp...");
          //     sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("connecting to sftp...");
             sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            client.connect();
            System.out.println("SFTP Connection established 
successfully.");
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("SFTP Connection established successfully.");
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

            String path1="/sftp/content-providers/tho-e/data/incoming
/scopusbk";
            com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPFile[] directroy = 
client.directoryList(path1);
            System.out.println("Total Number of Files Found 
:"+directroy.length);

          //  Arrays.sort(directroy);
         //   FTpFileComparator[] comp = new 
FTpFileComparator[files.length];

            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            //sb.append("Total Number of Files Found 
:"+directroy.length);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            int x=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < directroy.length; i++) 
            {
                //System.out.println("entered in for loop");
                Filename= new File(directroy[i].getName());
                FileDate=(Date) directroy[i].lastModified();
                //Filetype=getFileExtension(Filename);
            //  System.out.println("Name:"+Filename);

Lastmodifieddata=dateformat.format(directroy[i].lastModified());

Lastmodifieddata_time=Format_time.format(directroy[i].lastModified());

                //filesize=directroy[i].getName().getBytes();
                long size = directroy[i].size();

                if(timeStamp.equalsIgnoreCase(Lastmodifieddata))


                {   
                    if ((directroy[i]).getName().endsWith("txt"))
                    {

                System.out.println("File Name : "+Filename + " ||  
Upload Time :  "+Lastmodifieddata_time+"  || Size  : "+size+" kb");
                 sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                sb.append("File Name : "+Filename + " ||  Upload Time :  
"+Lastmodifieddata_time+"  ||  Size  : "+size+" kb");
                 sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                //System.out.println();


                // String path1="/sftp/suppliers/thomdi/signals
/ContentCAR";
                // com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPFile[] directroy = 
client.directoryList(path1);
                count++;
                    //}
            }

           }

                else
                {
                    //System.out.println("No todays files");
                }
     }
            if(count>0)
            {
            System.out.println("Total Number of files :"+count);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            sb.append("Total Number of file :"+count);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());          

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No Files uploaded today....!!!");
                  sb.append("No Files uploaded today....!!!");
            }


          //  PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new 
FileOutputStream("D:/output.txt"));
          //  System.setOut(out);
            if(!logfile.exists())
            {
            logfile.createNewFile();
            }
                FileUtils.writeStringToFile(logfile,sb.toString());

            FTPMailer.sendmailFTP();

            count=0;


     }
     catch(SecurityException se)
     {
         System.out.println("Security credentials mismatch 
 issue...Unable to Login ");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         sb.append("Security credentials mismatch issue...Unable to 
Login ");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         se.printStackTrace();

     }
     catch(ConnectException ce)
     {
         System.out.println("Unable to Reach FTP Server..");
         System.out.println("Check the Internet Connectivity");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         sb.append("Unable to Reach FTP Server..");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
         sb.append("Check the Internet Connectivity");
         sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
     }

 }
 }
```

|Kindly help I have googled a lot but am not able to reach FTP file sorting.

Any help will be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to sort `FTPFile[]` in descending order (assuming that the last modified time is the uploaded time).

```
Arrays.sort(ftpfiles, new Comparator<FTPFile>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(FTPFile o1, FTPFile o2) {
        return o2.lastModified().compareTo(o1.lastModified());
    }
});
```

to print the three recent uploaded files (after sorting the array)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3) {
    // amend the output for your needs
    System.out.printn(ftpfiles[i]);
}
```

Code is not tested. Written based on the javadoc of [FTPFile](https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/doc/api/com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/FTPFile.html).

**edit** Small snippet tested with the free library version.

```
import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPFile;
...
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create an array of dummy files
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    FTPFile[] ftpfiles = new FTPFile[5];
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    ftpfiles[0] = new FTPFile("raw", "file1", 111, false, cal.getTime());
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    ftpfiles[1] = new FTPFile("raw", "file5", 555, false, cal.getTime());
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
    ftpfiles[2] = new FTPFile("raw", "file3", 333, false, cal.getTime());
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 4);
    ftpfiles[3] = new FTPFile("raw", "file4", 444, false, cal.getTime());
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 2);
    ftpfiles[4] = new FTPFile("raw", "file2", 222, false, cal.getTime());

    System.out.println("unsorted file list");
    for (FTPFile ftpfile : ftpfiles) {
        printFileInfo(ftpfile);
    }

    // sort array by last modification time in descending order
    Arrays.sort(ftpfiles, new Comparator<FTPFile>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(FTPFile o1, FTPFile o2) {
            return o2.lastModified().compareTo(o1.lastModified());
        }
    });

    System.out.println("sorted file list");
    for (FTPFile ftpfile : ftpfiles) {
        printFileInfo(ftpfile);
    }

    System.out.println("the three recent files only");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printFileInfo(ftpfiles[i]);
    }

}

static void printFileInfo(FTPFile ftpfile) {
    System.out.printf("name: %s  mtime: %s  size: %d%n",
            ftpfile.getName(),
            ftpfile.lastModified(),
            ftpfile.size()
    );
}
```

output

```
unsorted file list
name: file1  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:01 CET 2016  size: 111
name: file5  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:05 CET 2016  size: 555
name: file3  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:03 CET 2016  size: 333
name: file4  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:04 CET 2016  size: 444
name: file2  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:02 CET 2016  size: 222

sorted file list
name: file5  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:05 CET 2016  size: 555
name: file4  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:04 CET 2016  size: 444
name: file3  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:03 CET 2016  size: 333
name: file2  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:02 CET 2016  size: 222
name: file1  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:01 CET 2016  size: 111

the three recent files only
name: file5  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:05 CET 2016  size: 555
name: file4  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:04 CET 2016  size: 444
name: file3  mtime: Fri Feb 12 12:23:03 CET 2016  size: 333
```

Comment: Thank you sir.I am getting compile time error ,uploaded the error screen shot.kindly see me edit and request you to help me to come over from this.

Comment: Need to print the Last three uploaded files properties as upload time,size,file name.Kindly help sir

Comment: @
SubOptimal  kindly help me sir

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman Fix your import. As you are already using `import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.*` replace `import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;` by `import com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPFile;`.

Comment: @ SubOptimal  : Thank you sir.Thanks a lot for your help.it helped a lot.

Comment: can you please help me to get the size of those three file.I tried with  byte[] size1 = directroy[i1].getName().getBytes(); but it returns as a junk (  size : [B@9e4dc0 kb) and it is not in the format

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman As an element in `directories[]` is of type `FTPFile` you have to use the method [size()](https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/doc/api/com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/FTPFile.html#size) on that `FTPFile` object. Not on its name (getName() return the name of the file entry).

Comment: superb sir.Thank you.But when i run this am getting a file details with filename as . ( only dot)and its absolutely no need.please help me to get the exact last uploaded text files with ext (.txt).please have a look on my edit for screen shot.

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman Serveral possiblitites: **1)** sort filelist in a way that directories are at the end, **2)** remove directory entries before sorting from the list, **3)** implement a `DirectoryListCallback` [SecureFileTransferClient.html#directoryList](https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/doc/api/com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/SecureFileTransferClient.html#directoryList(java.lang.String,%20com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.DirectoryListCallback)), **4)** use the [support from EnterpriseDT](https://enterprisedt.com/support/), as you are using the PRO version this should be possible